# Hot reload always fails on Ionic React

Tags: ionic-framework

I’m using the command `ionic cap run android -l --external` on my ionic react project that I’ve created with `ionic start my-app --type=react --no-ts`. However, even though it asks me to select the device correctly and then it asks which IP on my computer I want the application to run, it fails just after the development server starts… Here is what happens when I try to execute it:

```
ionic cap run android -l --external
? Which device would you like to target? samsung SM-G970F
> capacitor sync android
[capacitor] ✔ Copying web assets from build to android/app/src/main/assets/public in 227.67ms
[capacitor] ✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in android/app/src/main/assets in 1.48ms
[capacitor] ✔ copy android in 264.96ms
[capacitor] ✔ Updating Android plugins in 9.11ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for android:
[capacitor]        @capacitor/app@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/haptics@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/keyboard@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/status-bar@5.0.6
[capacitor] ✔ update android in 75.62ms
[capacitor] [info] Sync finished in 0.343s
[WARN] Multiple network interfaces detected!
       
       You will be prompted to select an external-facing IP for the dev server that your device or emulator can access.
       Make sure your device is on the same Wi-Fi network as your computer. Learn more about Live Reload in the docs[1].
       
       To bypass this prompt, use the --public-host option (e.g. --public-host=10.20.0.111). You can alternatively bind
       the dev server to a specific IP (e.g. --host=10.20.0.111).
       
       [1]: https://ion.link/livereload-docs
       
? Please select which IP to use: 10.20.0.111 (wlo1)
> react-scripts start
[react-scripts] Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: 0.0.0.0
[react-scripts] If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
[react-scripts] Learn more here: https://cra.link/advanced-config
[react-scripts] (node:1140815) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[react-scripts] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[react-scripts] (node:1140815) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[react-scripts] Starting the development server...
[react-scripts] 
[react-scripts] You can now view my-app in the browser.
[react-scripts]   Local:            http://localhost:8101
[react-scripts]   On Your Network:  http://10.20.0.111:8101
[react-scripts] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[react-scripts] To create a production build, use npm run build.

[INFO] Development server running!
       
       Local: http://localhost:8101
       External: http://10.20.0.111:8101, http://172.20.0.1:8101, http://172.19.0.1:8101, http://172.26.0.1:8101,
       http://172.21.0.1:8101, http://172.22.0.1:8101, http://172.18.0.1:8101, http://172.17.0.1:8101
       
       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EINVAL
    at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:874:20)
    at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:747:19)
    at Object.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/events.js:12:13)
    at ReactServeRunner.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/serve.js:175:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RunCommand.runServe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/commands/capacitor/base.js:191:33)
    at async RunCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/commands/capacitor/run.js:220:13)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async RunCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/command.js:81:9)
    at async Executor.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/executor.js:54:9)
Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
    at processEmit [as emit] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:199:34)
    at node:internal/child_process:878:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  errno: -22,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

Here are the versions of `node.js`, `npm` and OS that I’m using:

```
node.js- v18.14.0
npm- 8.19.2
Ubuntu 22.04
```

And in my project, I’m using the following `@capacitor/cli` and `@ionic/cli`

```
├── @capacitor/android@5.2.2
├── @capacitor/app@5.0.6
├── @capacitor/cli@5.2.1
├── @capacitor/core@5.2.2
├── @capacitor/haptics@5.0.6
├── @capacitor/keyboard@5.0.6
├── @capacitor/status-bar@5.0.6
├── @ionic/cli@6.20.9
├── @ionic/react-router@7.2.1
├── @ionic/react@7.2.1
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.17.0
├── @testing-library/react@13.4.0
├── @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
├── @types/jest@26.0.24
├── @types/node@12.20.55
├── @types/react-dom@18.2.7
├── @types/react-router-dom@5.3.3
├── @types/react-router@5.1.20
├── @types/react@18.2.18
├── @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0
├── @typescript-eslint/parser@5.62.0
├── eslint-plugin-react@7.33.1
├── eslint@8.46.0
├── history@4.10.1
├── ionicons@7.1.2
├── react-dom@18.2.0
```

When I run `npm start` my project runs perfectly fine. However, the commands `ionic cap run android -l --external` and `ionic serve` always return the first error I showed here. I’ve tried changing the versions of `npm`, `node.js`, `@ionic/cli` and `@capacitor/cli` to different ones but no matter which version I choose the error is always there. What is happening? Why does the hot reload fail to start? That's basically an application created from scratch with the official ionic tools.

---

Even though I’m successfully running my projects with `npm start`, as far as I understood the hot reload functionality would allow me to see the changes in my frontend development in real-time while getting data from the phone. I've been using the command `ionic capacitor run android --target=my-device-number` to deploy the application to my phone but it takes too long, the hot reload would be better for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try, for testing, following the [ionic-team/capacitor ~ Getting Started](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor#getting-started) section, a separate new project:

```bash
ionic start myNewApp blank --type=react
cd myNewApp
ionic integrations enable capacitor
npx cap init
ionic cap run android -l --external
```

With:

- `-l` enables live reload.
- `--external` allows devices on the same network to access the dev server.

When prompted, choose the device you want to run on. Make sure the device is connected to your development machine and that both the machine and the device are on the same network.
Check your firewalls or other network configurations must allow traffic between the device and your development machine.

When you run with `--external`, you will often be prompted to choose an IP address to use. That should be an IP address that is reachable from your testing device.

I have seen the `error "write EINVAL"` referenced quite a lot in [`nodejs/node` issue 16141](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16141), so you might have to switch version (for instance, using using [`nvm` (Node Version Manager)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to switch between different Node versions for different projects), just to check if this is a version compatibility issue.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a vpn? Sounds like there's an issue with your host connection.

Try turning off vpn  and try again. Sounds like a firewall or something is blocking the app from live reload.

Ionic provides a plugin for VS code, that supports many functions that help with running / turning on/off live reload.